# UIGraphicsImageRenderer does not see some content on PDFPage

Tags: swift, cgpdfdocument, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I use code from huckingwithswift.com as it is:

```
private func imageFromPDF(page: CGPDFPage) -> UIImage {
    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()
        ctx.fill(pageRect)
        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }
    return image
}
```

, and on previous examples (QRCode in PDF) it works good. Now a test ingeneer reported that my application can not see QRCodes on such page: [image]

UIGraphicsImageRenderer creates an image, which looks like [image]
You can see, it does not see this QRCodes
It may be because of different layers, but how to make all content be visible?